# FormArray.insert adds element in wrong position

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular application that computes formulas defined by a user. Each operand is displayed as a`mat-chip`, which can be clicked to set that position as the start for adding new operands. My component looks like this:

```
export class ServiceComponent implements OnInit {

// stores the position where to add new operands
selectedChipIndex: number;

// updates the selectedChipIndex
clickOnChip(formulaType: any, index?: number): void {
    if (index) {
      this.selectedChipIndex = index;
    } else {
      this.selectedChipIndex = undefined;
    }
  }

// adds the new operand
append(valueToAdd: string) {
    let fr = this.form.get(this.formula) as FormArray;
    if (this.selectedChipIndex != undefined) {
      // insert in the following position
      fr.insert(this.selectedChipIndex+1, valueToAdd)
      // update the selectedChipIndex for next insertion
      this.selectedChipIndex += 1;
    } else {
      // insert at end
      fr.push(valueToAdd);
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine as long as this.selectedChipIndex is not 0, i.e. if `this.selectedChipIndex == 1`, `fr == ['1','+','2']` and `valueToAdd == 5`, the resulting formula will be `['1','+','5','2']`.

However, when `this.selectedChipIndex == 0`, the resulting formula will be `['1','+','2','5']` (instead of `['1','5','+','2']`). Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into a classic truthiness pitfall.

In your `clickOnChip` function, the if statement will always evaluate `0` as false. As a result, when the `index` is `0`, the `selectedChipIndex` is set to `undefined`. You need to explicitly check for `undefined` using `if( x !== undefined)` patterns.

Here are a few example of truthiness:

```js
/**********************
* Don't ever do these!!
***********************/

const myString = '';
if(myString) // return false

const myNum = 0;
if(myNum)  // return false

const myUndefined = undefined;
if(myUndefined) // return false;

const myNull = null;
if(myNull) // return false;

/**********************
* DO these instead!!!
***********************/

const myString = '';
if(myString !== '')

const myNum = 0;
if(myNum !== 0)

const myUndefined = undefined;
if(myUndefined !== undefined)

const myNull = null;
if(myNull !== null)
```

---

I updated your code to make it better. First of all, you can't set `_selectedChipIndex` to `undefined` if it is only of type `number`. You need to make it a union type of `number` and `undefined`.

Then in the `clickOnChip` function, you can just set the `index` value to the `this._selectedChipIndex`.

```js
private _selectedChipIndex: number | undefined;

clickOnChip(formulaType: unknown, index?: number) {

  this._selectedChipIndex = index;

  if(index === undefined)
     console.log('do something when index is undefined!');
  else
     console.log('Index: ', index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if index is equal to 0, then this condition in your code:

```
   // index equals 0
   if (index)
```

will return false.

This is why it always goes to the "else" part:

```
this.selectedChipIndex = undefined;
```

Just change your condition to

```
if (index !== undefined)
```

will fix the problem as the position will be set correctly.